# Position database variable

Tags: php, sql

Database + code:

```
number | Photo_id | Photo| 
1        1          img.jpg 
1        2          img2.jpg
2        1          photo.jpg
```

etc.

```
while(list($nummer, $foto_id, $foto) = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
echo "<image class=\"foto\" src=\"images/foto/$foto\">";
}
```

Question:

I Get the photo out of the database and put it in variable $photo. When I position img.foto in css it moves all the images I get out of the db obviously. If I echo $photo, how will I still be able to position every photo individually with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify them a unique `id` attribute. You need to make sure than `$nummber` is unique value for each photo:

```
while(list($nummer, $foto_id, $foto) = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<img class=\"foto\" id=\"photo-{$nummer}\" src=\"images/foto/{$foto}\">";
}
```

then in CSS:

```
#photo-1 { position: ...; },
#photo-2 { position: ...; },
#photo-(n) { position: ...; }
...
```

Comment: Caution, there will be two #photo-1 in the same page with this.

Comment: Yes, you are right, he needs the value of the unique key.

Comment: For some reason the exact same question was put on hold couple of days ago. Anyway this got it working for me, thank you very much!

Comment: The question title is wrong... better title would be "Distinction between images names fetched from a database" or something similar

Answer (score 0):

The tag is `<img>` not `<image>`. You can select the nth-child in CSS 3. For a solution without CSS 3, you can do:

```
for($i = 1; list($nummer, $foto_id, $foto) = mysql_fetch_row($result); $i++)
{
    echo "<img class=\"foto f" . $i . "\" src=\"images/foto/$foto\">";
}
```

And in your CSS : img.foto.f1, img.foto.f2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your number to load another css class to add your number behind your class. I have modified your code a bit that its more readable.

```
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<image class="foto-{$res['number']}" src="images/foto/{$res['foto']}">';
}
```

Edit: If the number is not unique. Then you have to use an iterator.

```
$i = 1;
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<image class="foto-{$i}" src="images/foto/{$res['foto']}">';
    $i++;
}
```

You can do it with for, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the style attribute for every  tag. With the PHP function getimagesize http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php you can find out the width/height of each image and build up needed css values. You also could use a HTML table or other position elements to get a output.